# Laravel 5 / Eloquent - Handling Array Parameters in Dynamic Where Method Input

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a repository function that gets data by using:

```
public function get($request){

    return User::where($request)->get();    

}
```

where the `$request` array is dynamic.  The above works well as long as I pass in regular key value pairs:

```
$request = array(
    'name' => 'mike',
    'age' => 45
);
```

The above translates to this SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE name = 'mike' AND age = 45;
```

Every once in a while, I would like to pass in an array as one of the properties for `$request`:

```
$request = array(
    'name' => 'mike',
    'age' => array(45, 46)
)
```

and have it translate into the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE name = 'mike' AND age IN(45, 46);
```

Any properties set as an array in `$request` should be treated as a `where in` statement as opposed to a vanilla `where` statement.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should handle it nicely...

```
public function get($request)
{
    $query = User::query();
    foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $query->whereIn($key, $value);
        } else {
            $query->where($key, $value);
        }
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

Comment: `newQuery()` isn't a static method.  Anyway to do this without instantiating a new instance of my model?

Comment: Just use query() instead of newQuery().

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the whereIn statement, something like:

```
User::where(['name' => 'jhon'])->whereIn(['age' => [45, 46])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `when()` method https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#conditional-clauses

In your case it would be:

```
public function get($request)
{
    $query = User::newQuery();

    foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
        $query->when(is_array($value), function($query)
        {
            return $query->whereIn($key, $value);
        }, function($query) use($key, $value)
        {
            return $query->where($key, $value);
        });
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```